# Sorting 2D String Array by date and number in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have a `String[][]` array with following data. I want to sort this array

1. according to the integer value in column  `data[][1]`,
2. according to the date in column `data[][2]`. Output should be 2D String array.

> ```
> String[][] data = {
>     {"text", "5", "Fri, 04 Feb 2011 13:17:31 GMT"},
>     {"text", "5", "Fri, 04 Feb 2011 14:24:47 GMT"},
>     {"text", "8", "Fri, 05 Sep 2014 20:43:57 GMT"},
>     {"text", "4", "Fri, 08 Nov 2013 16:35:34 GMT"},
>     {"text", "4", "Fri, 15 Aug 2014 10:00:16 GMT"},
>     {"text", "4", "Fri, 16 May 2014 15:03:08 GMT"},
>     {"text", "6", "Fri, 31 Jan 2014 13:12:06 GMT"},
>     {"text", "4", "Mon, 04 Aug 2014 09:14:36 GMT"},
>     {"text", "4", "Mon, 08 Sep 2014 03:55:54 GMT"},
>     {"text", "1", "Mon, 08 Sep 2014 12:53:09 GMT"}
> };
> ```

Comment: what is the desired output? is it again a 2D-String[][] ?

Comment: Yes. 2D String. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope sorting the integer won't be a issue to you i will show you how you can **sort according to date**

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() { // sort the array
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    // SimpleDateFormat  to parse the String Date
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        try {
            return f.parse(o1[2]).compareTo(f.parse(o2[2]));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
});
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ // display the result
    for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(data[i][j]);
        if(j < data[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Wrap the Array into a list using `Arrays.asList`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29

Now use `Collections.sort` and create a custom `Comparator` that reads the data from the arrays inside the list and sorts accordingly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

First compare on the integer, if the integers are the same then parse the string into a Date and compare the two Date objects.

Comment: your post is not very newbie-friendly but ist totally correct!!

Comment: @MartinFrank It has all the information he needs, I'm not going to write his code for him :) If he has specific questions he wants to add when trying to follow this I'll be happy to answer them though.

Comment: 100% agreed! i didn't mean to criticise you instead i apprechiate (damn english, sorry) your approach!

Comment: Also possible to sort using `Arrays.sort(Object[], Comparator)`.